# Increase space / height between TListView items (and TTreeView items) on Windows larger items selection

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-2009, c++builder-2010

I use Borland C++ Builder 2009 (yet I assume the issue and solution is the same for Delphi) and right now I assume the answer I'm looking for is the same for both `TListView` items and `TTreeView` items.  I may be wrong !?

I have noticed, on a smaller Win 8.1 laptop with Display setting 'Change the size of all items' set to 125% . That the items in both TreeView and ListView get closer to each other.

I haven't tested 150% yet, I assume it will be worse.

I would like to adjust for that if possible.
I assume the same logic goes for when a larger sized font is chosen to display these items ?

1. How would you test if the height of the items is 'too' big and the items need a bit more space between them ?
2. And how would you increase the spacing between them ?  Taking in account that my ListView implementation is virtual (`ListView->OwnerData = true ;`) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TForm has *Scaled* property. If it is *true*, all components on a form should be resized automatically accordingly to font size. I cannot check right now if this works for TListView and TTreeView, but you should check this property anyway.

Comment: Scaled is set to false.  This is historical, I have been taking this with me probably since I first created the project more than 16 years ago.  Not sure why.  I think however that my question is good for the trash anyway.  I don't know why I felt it was not looking so great but I have been running a few tests and turns out both TreeView and listView deal with things pretty good !!!!  I increased the size of the font dramatically and it still displayed great.  Fact is that all the rest is not so great ... status bar, combobox, lables on panels etc.  Scale doesn't affect those btw.

Comment: Long story short.  I should leave this as is and concentrate on resizing all the other things, also the height of the Menu and Popup items, but there's an event for that (untried at this stage, but I'm sure it will work).  So I will go ahead and accept your answer.  It's the best answer to give considering.

Comment: I have asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324974/determine-height-of-text-in-tmenuitem-to-decide-to-what-height-to-change-the-men