# Determine Height of text in TMenuItem to decide to what height to change the MenuItem via TMenuItem.OnMeasureItem

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, delphi-2009, c++builder-2010

I use Borland C++ Builder 2009 and when a large font is used, the Menu items in MainMenu and Popup are too close to each other, text cut off on top and bottom even, when too big.

I understand I can change the height of the items with `TMenuItem.OnMeasureItem` but to what height should I set it ?

What's the best way to calculate an ideal height and how do I get the variables for it (e.g. height of text)?

Comment: Look at the `TCanvas.TextHeight()` method.  Create a temp `TCanvas`, assign the current `Screen.MenuFont` to it, pass the `TMenuItem.Caption` to its `TextHeight()`, and then free it.  Or, since VCL menus already handle `WM_MEASUREITEM` internally, debug into the VCL source code to find out why the default heights are too small and then fix it.

Comment: Best solution is to change VCL code to stop using owner draw menus

Comment: I use the suggested `TCanvas.TextHeight()` function, and add some padding on top and below, and feed that value via `TMenuItem.OnMeasureItem` back during the drawing.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

`OnMeasureItem` handlers suggests you default value in `Height` var parameter.

You can multiply this value by ratio of current screen PPI and default PPI for font size 100% (96), e.g. `Height := Ceil(Height * Screen.PixelsPerInch / 96);`